# MATLAB Broadcasting for unifrnd

Tags: arrays, matlab, size, array-broadcasting

I am coming back from `NumPy` to `MATLAB` and don't quite have the hang of the broadcasting here.
Can someone explain to me why the first one fails and the second (more explicit works)?
After my understanding, `x0` and `x1` are both `1x2` arrays and it should be possible to extend them to `5x2`.

```
n_a = 5;
n_b = 2;

x0 = [1, 2];
x1 = [11, 22];

% c = unifrnd(x0, x1, [n_a, n_b])
% Error using unifrnd
% Size information is inconsistent.
% c = unifrnd(x0, x1, [n_a, 1])  % also fails

c = unifrnd(ones(n_a, n_b) .* x0, ones(n_a, n_b) .* x1, [n_a, n_b])
% works
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a size verification within the `unifrnd` function (you can type `open unifrnd` in the command line to see the function code). It sends the error if the third input is not coherent with the size of the first 2 inputs:

```
[err, sizeOut] = internal.stats.statsizechk(2,a,b,varargin{:});
if err > 0
    error(message('stats:unifrnd:InputSizeMismatch'));
end
```

If you skip this part, though (as in if you create a custom function without the size check), both your function calls that fail will actually work, due to implicit expansion. The real question is whether calling the function this way makes sense.

TL;DR : It is not the broadcasting that fails, it is the function that does not allow you these sets of inputs

Answer (score 2):

`unifrnd` essentially calls `rand` and applies scaling and shifting to the desired interval. So you can use `rand` and do the scaling and shifting manually, which allows you to employ broadcasting (singleton expansion):

```
c = x0 + (x1-x0).*rand(n_a, n_b);
```